# Android TextView's default values like height, font-size, line-spacing, padding, margin

Tags: android, textview

Thanks in advance for your time.

As per the image below, I'm looking for the default values for the Android `TextView` but am having a difficult time locating this information.

I am aware about `lineSpacingExtra` and multipliers but these don't tell me what the default values.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Look at [Dense layouts](https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-text-field-boxes) paragraph from material design guidlines
[image]

**Normal spacing**
Height: 56dp
Padding above label: 8dp
Padding below label: 8dp
Padding below text field: 8dp
Padding above helper text: 8dp

Answer (score 0):

You can set a fix height of textview like that

```
android:layout_height="40dp"
```

OR you can set a bydefault height of textview then

```
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and some space given a layout right,left,above,below side then using  `android:padding="5dp"`